# Android string formatting

Tags: android, string, format

I have a textview that I'm setting the text from a value obtained from a SimpleCursorAdapter.  The field in my SQLite database is a REAL number.  Here is my code:

```
        // Create the idno textview with background image
        TextView idno = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.idno);
        idno.setText(cursor.getString(3));
```

My issue is that the text display a decimal.  The value is 1081, but I'm getting 1081.0000.  How can I convert the string to not display the decimals?  I've looked into the formatter, but I can't get the syntax right.

```
        TextView idno = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.idno);
        String idno = cursor.getString(3);
        idno.format("@f4.0");
        idno.setText(idno);
```

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `String.format`:

```
String idno = String.format("%1$.0f", cursor.getDouble(3));
```

Can also you `DecimalFormat`:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#");
String idno = df.format(cursor.getDouble(3));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  It worked great.  I did have to use a different variable name as I was using idno for the textview as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you get a `String` with a decimal point, you can simply do:

```
idno.setText(cursor.getString(3).split("\\.")[0]);
//          Split where there is a point--^   ^
//                                            |
//          Get the first in the array--------+
```

Note that this:

```
TextView idno = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.idno);
String idno = cursor.getString(3);
```

is illegal, as you use the same variable name.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I did figure out the duplicate variable name when I tried to run. ;-D